# How can I specify the database table name for a model in PHPixie?

Tags: php, phpixie

I've got an error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'phpixie.persons' doesn't exist

when queuering table 'people':

```
public function getPerson($person_id)
{
    return $this->components()->orm()->query('person')
        ->where('id', $person_id)
        ->findOne();
}
```

From [documentation](https://phpixie.com/components/orm.html):

> By default ORM assumes that the table name is the plural of the name
>   of the model, and that the name of the primary key is ‘id’.

How can i specify table name directly?

PS Or specify rules list like [EnglishPluralizationService](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/PluralizationService/EnglishPluralizationService.cs):

> {"child", "children"} {"corpus","corpora"} {"person", "people"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which version of PHPixie you are using, there are different solutions to specify the table name for a model:

#### `2.x`

Assuming you already have a `Person` model, you can specify the table name using the `$table` field:

```
class Person extends \PHPixie\ORM\Model
{
     public $table = 'person';
}
```

For reference, see:

- https://phpixie.com/2.x/orm.html

#### `3.x`

You can override the default assumptions in your configuration file:

```
return array(
    'models' => array(
        'person' => array(
            'table'=> 'persons',
        ),
    );
);
```

For reference, see:

- https://phpixie.com/components/orm.html#configuration

Comment: is it works for phpixie 3? i've created \bundles\app\src\ORM\Model\Person.php but it doesn't work

Comment: Adjusted the answer to include instructions for `3.x`!

Answer (score 1):

Phpixie3:

```
<?php
// bundles/app/assets/config/orm.php
return [
    'models' => [
        'person' => [
            'table' => 'people',
            // if you want to change id field also:
            'id'    => 'pid',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Call with:

```
$builder->components()->orm()->query('person')->in(432)->findOne();
```

Should become

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE id=432;
```

or, if you also overriden id field:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE pid=432;
```